# How to change the input from a String to a scanner input and then use it in my code

Tags: java

For my final project, I am attempting to change the input in the tester class from a string to a scanner input

Here is the original line of code:

```
public class FinancialCalculatorTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       FinancialCalculator.showCustomerInfo("Antonio Williams");
   }
}
```

The output comes to this:

> Name: Antonio Williams
> Age: 40 
>  Phone: (225)897-7865 
> Salary: 85043.0 
> Insurance: 2084.0
>   Monthly Expenses: 10000.0
>   Savings: 72959.0

(The information comes from the other class with all the information)

I would like to change it to something along the lines of:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinancialCalculatorTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);           
        FinancialCalculator.showCustomerInfo();
     }
 }
```

I want to do this because there is more than one name in the Array list and I want the user to choose what name they want. 
If needed, I can show the code for the other class.

**I want to choose a name from the other class and get an output of that names information (such as the original output seen above.)** Each name has their own output such as that one. 
Thank you!

Comment: you want a user to enter the name then choose one of the similar names in your array ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class FinancialCalculatorTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter name: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(FinancialCalculator.showCustomerInfo(input.nextLine()));       
 }
}
```

You mean this?

EDIT: You have to log the result of showCustomerInfo, assuming that this method returns a String with all the info mentioned.

Comment: Close, but I would like it to also print the other parts of the output (age, phone, salary, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Spend some time reading the [JSE API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) pages.

TLDR:

1. You can construct a `Scanner` object with an `InputStream` parameter.
2. Browsing the `InputStream` API page shows that there is a `ByteArrayInputStream` class.

Construct a ByteArrayInputStream from the String value then construct a Scanner from the ByteArrayInputStream.

The above is the result of a, likely, bad assumption on my part.

Go with what DogyCodeException suggests and construct the `Scanner` using the String as a constructor argument.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's what the OP meant (I didn't really understand the question) but if it was, then why construct a Scanner in such a roundabout way instead of constructing it directly with a String argument?